# Не изменяется мой сайт после изменения кода в html и css/

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь оформить рамку в заголовке,но ничего не меняется!

```
html строка:
<h1 align="center"class="My zagolovok">Вторая мировая война-война,изменившая 
мир.(1939-1945 г.)</h1>

css код:
my zagolovok{
color:gray;
background-color:gray;
border:3px solid #4e4a55;
}
```

Comment: class="MyZagolovok" сделайте и в css укажите с таким же именем .MyZagolovok  {...}

Comment: Сработало!спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Если в атрибуте `class` есть пробел, значит там 2 класса: `My` и `zagolovok`
можно сделать так:

```
.My.zagolovok { ... }
```

Или просто к одному из классов `.My { ... }`

Comment: спасибо!теперь буду знать!И у меня последний вопрос.У меня вместо заголовка просто рамка с серым фоном и никакого заголовка.В чём может быть проблема?Цвет текст чёрным делал

Comment: а,извиняюсь,уже понял косяк сам.Спасибо за помощь!